# how to catch next, prev, today event with fullcalendar for Angular 7 cli

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am implementing fullCalendar in my Angular 7 app, the calendar is working and i am importing some Events to it, but i am trying to do it more efficent, i am trying to bring just the events that the calendar needs.

So.. i have some questions.

How can i get the click event in the Prev or Next or Today button?

How can i get the current Date?

I have been checking the documentation... but there are only examples for jquery...

Here i copy my HTML

```
  <full-calendar id="calendar" *ngIf="options" #fullcalendar [editable]="true" [events]="citas"
    [header]="options.header" [locale]="options.locale" [customButtons]="options.customButtons"
    (dateClick)="dateClick($event)" [plugins]="options.plugins" (eventClick)="eventClick($event)" [eventLimit]="4">
  </full-calendar>
```

And my Ts

```
  @ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: FullCalendarComponent;

  constructor() {
    this.options = {

      editable: true,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth, listDay'
      },
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
      locale: esLocale,
    };

  }
```

Comment: "How can i get the click event in the Prev or Next or Today button?" ...there's no callback for this in fullCalendar, because it's not anticipated that you would need to handle these clicks. You'd have to write your own event handling code and attach it to those elements. But why do you want to do it? What do you want to happen when those buttons are clicked? In my experience there is rarely a good reason for this. This gets asked a lot, and the people who ask it almost always want to do something for which there is a better way...

Comment: "there are only examples for jquery"...I doubt it, since fullCalendar v4 doesn't use jQuery. Maybe you just mean JavaScript?

Comment: "How can i get the current Date" ...call the [getDate()](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getDate) method. The docs for the [Angular Component](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular) explain about doing this (in the section called "Accessing fullCalendar's API").

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your quick answer, i would like to get these events because, for example if i am in dayGridView and i press next, i would like to take from my db just the events for the next day, or if i am in monthGridView get the events for the next month. And about the Date... i would like to get current Date everytime it changes... would you recomend me to use other tool?

Comment: Yes I would. fullCalendar can handle the fetching of new events for you automatically. In the simplest case you can either simply give it a URL at your server from where it can get a JSON feed of events - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed. FullCalendar will visit the URL whenever the user changes the date on the calendar (using next/prev/today buttons), or if they change the view in such a way as to need more data (e.g. from day to month). It will automatically send the new start and end dates to the server as parameters, and the server just has to send back the right events.

Comment: If you need a bit more flexibility than that, then you can define a custom callback function as the source of events instead - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. The idea is the same - fullCalendar will call the function whenever it needs more data, and then it's up to you to implement whatever code you need/want in order to generate the event data. Either of these methods is much neater than handling all that yourself via the buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to plugin's [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular#accessing-fullcalendars-api), you have access to the underlying `Calendar` object for raw data and methods:

```
const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
```

The complete list of methods for Date Navigation the can be found here:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-navigation.

So, to get the current date we can use: `calendarApi.getDate();`.

The following code should work:

```
export class AppComponent {

  // references the #calendar in the template
  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;


  someMethod() {
    const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
    const currentDate = calendarApi.getDate();
    console.log("The current date of the calendar is " + currentDate);
  }
  
}
```

I haven't found any events emitted for prev and next buttons, but you can build your own buttons by using `calendar.prev()` and `calendar.next()` methods.

```
  goPrev() {
    const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
    calendarApi.next(); // call a method on the Calendar object
  }
```

Comment: I've also played with an example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcwzaq. There is an event `datesRender` that is triggered on every time the calendar changes, that returns an object where maybe you can find some useful information.

Comment: wow that is exacly what i needed!  (datesRender)="handleDatesRender($event)" provides me the info that i needed

Comment: Thanks @andreivictor, your solution perfectly fits with my problem

Comment: Thanks @andreivictor , you made my day

Answer (score 3):

I Know  I'm late, but I want to shar with your my solution, so:
in your calendarOptions, you can add customButtons property, then add your newNextFunct to fullCalendar function like this:

```js
customButtons: {
    next: {
        click: this.nextMonth.bind(this),
    },
    prev: {
        click: this.prevMonth.bind(this),
    },
    today: {
        text: "Aujourd'hui",
        click: this.currentMonth.bind(this),
    },
},
```

your newNextFunction named as nextMonth must be like this:

```js
nextMonth(): void {
    console.warn('nextMonth');
    this.calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
    this.calendarApi.next();
}
```

**EDITED: (dynamic solution)**

If you're trying to do something when grid change (Month, day, list, next prev, today..etc, think to use **datesSet**

for exp, if you need to load data every time grid chaneged...this is your function to load data

```js
handleEvents(event: EventApi | any): void {
    if (this.calendarComponent) {
      this.calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
      this.currentDate = dayjs(this.calendarApi.view.currentStart).startOf('day');
      this.loadData();
    }
    this.currentEvents = event;
  }
```

and in your calendarOptions, add this line...

```
datesSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this)
```